# Are irreducible, positiv-definite Markov chains aperiodic?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, monte-carlo

If $M$ is the transition matrix of a discrete Markov chain, and $M$ is both irreducible, symmetric and positiv-definite, is the resulting Markov chain necessarily aperiodic?

In my intuition, periodicity would correspond to an $-1$-eigenvalue of $M$, but I don't know if that is true or how to formalize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so... Here's my thought.

Let $M$ be  an irreducible, symmetric and positive-definite $n\times n$ stochastic matrix, with spectrum $\sigma(M)=\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n\}$.

- Since $M$ is stochastic, we have that $\lambda_1=1$.
- Since $M$ is symmetric we have that $M$ is diagonalizable.
- Since $M$ is positive definite, we have that all eigenvalues of $M$ are positive.

Thus, there exists an invertible matrix $U$ s.t.:

$$M= U \cdot J\cdot U^{-1},$$
where $J=\begin{bmatrix} 1  &&&\\ & \lambda_2 & \\ &&\ddots &\\ &&&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$ is the Jordan normal form of $M$.

By [Perron - Frobenius theorem for non - negative, irreducible matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron-Frobenius_theorem#Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_matrices), we have that eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$, which happens to be the spectral radius of $M$ has algebraic multiplicity $1$ and for all other eigenvalues we have $$|\lambda_i|=\lambda_i<1, \, i=2, \ldots, n.$$

Thus, 
$$\begin{array}[t]{l}
M^k=U\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1^k & && \\ & \lambda_2^k  && \\ &&\ddots & \\ &&& \lambda_n^k\end{bmatrix}\cdot U^{-1}\\\\
 \lim_{k\to\infty}M^k=U\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & && \\ & 0  && \\ &&\ddots & \\ &&&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot U^{-1} \end{array}$$
must be a stochastic matrix, since $M^k$ is a stochastic matrix for every $k\in \mathbb N$.

Now it is easy to prove that 
$$ U \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & && \\ & 0  && \\ &&\ddots & \\ &&&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot U^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \pi_1 & \pi_2 & \cdots & \pi_n\\
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \cdots & \pi_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\pi_1 & \pi_2 & \cdots & \pi_n\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{\Pi}$$
plus $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i =1$.

Thus, $M$ must be aperiodic, since $\lim_{k\to\infty}M^k$ exists and equals to  a stochastic matrix with identical rows.

**Note**: We can prove that $\mathbf{\Pi}$ has all its elements strictly positive, since $$\pi = \begin{bmatrix} \pi_1 & \cdots & \pi_n\end{bmatrix}$$ is a left eigenvector which corresponds to Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

Comment: And why does that convergence imply aperiodicity?

Comment: @Bananach Let's say we have periodicity $d$. Then the sequence $\left\{M^k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ would not converge to a matrix, but we would have $d$ subsequences that would converge to different matrices.

Comment: And why does periodicity imply nonconvergence? :D   It does not imply pointwise nonconvergence, so I think there is at least a small argument missing

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your  comment:

Let $P$ be a stochastic, irreducible matrix. Since $P$ is irreducible it will be either aperiodic or periodic.

$P$ aperiodic$\iff\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}P^k$ exists.

$P$  periodic  matrix  with period $d>1$ $\iff \displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}P^k$ does not exist.

We can prove the latter using **cyclic subclasses**.

Answer (score 1):

It follows immediately from the [definition of positive definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix) that  $M_{i,i} = (e_i, M e_i)>0$ for all $i$. That is, all diagonal elements of $M$ are *strictly* positive. This implies aperiodicity of the resulting chain.